# Difference between Callable and FunctionType

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing, callable-object

I am trying to properly type hint my code and encountered both [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) and [FunctionType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=functiontype#types.FunctionType)

```py
from typing import Callable
def my_func() -> Callable:
    f = lambda: _
    return f

result = my_func()
type(result)  # <class 'function'>
isinstance(result, Callable)  # True
```

vs

```py
from types import FunctionType
def my_func() -> FunctionType
    f = lambda: ...
    return f

result = my_func()
type(result)  # <class 'function'>
isinstance(result, FunctionType)  # True
```

One possible case I can think of is to distinguish between regular and class-based callables like this

```py
class C:
    def __call__(self):
        pass

def my_func() -> Callable:
    c = C()
    return c

result = my_func()
type(result)  # <class 'function'>
isinstance(result, Callable)  # True
isinstance(result, FunctionType)  # False
```

What are the differences between those and when I have to use one over the other?

Comment: You should use `Callable` unless you have a **very** good reason to do otherwise. `Callable` accepts generic parameters: say, `Callable[[int, str], None]` is any callable that takes two arguments (int and str) as positional parameters and returns `None`. `types.FunctionType` is more like an internal thing not intended for typechecking. You shouldn't have cases when function is acceptable and instance with `__call__` - not, it's very weird API.

Comment: Many things you call *don't* have type `function`: types (e.g., `int` and in your example  `C`), instance methods (the *class* attribute is a `function`, but the descriptor protocol produces a `method` instance that actually gets called), `functools.partial` instances, built-in functions like `id`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) is dynamically defined in [cpython/Lib/types.py#L11-L12](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f2fa03ff3d566b675020787e23de8fb4ca78e99/Lib/types.py#L11-L12) as the type of the simplest function.

```py
def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
```

[`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) on the other hand is defined as a wrapped [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable) which a) should be used directly if using python >= 3.9 and b) is itself defined in [cpython/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L534-L548](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f2fa03ff3d566b675020787e23de8fb4ca78e99/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L534-L548) as something having a `__call__` method.

```py
class Callable(metaclass=ABCMeta):  # NOTE: I'm skipping most of the definition

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Callable:
            return _check_methods(C, "__call__")
        return NotImplemented
```

You have highlighted correctly that nearly anything can be a callable, just need to give it a `__call__` method, on the other hand, a class will never be a function.

You should use `Callable` in most cases unless you are **completely certain you need a function only**.

Moreover, you can (and should) type the arguments and return value of `Callable`, for instance:

- `Callable[[], None]` -- no arg, returns `None` (e.g. `lambda: None`)
- `Callable[[int, int], int]` -- two `int` args, returns an `int`
- `Callable[..., None]` -- any arg, returns `None`, (e.g. `print`).